# mysql Unix timestamp check if 2 hours elasped

Tags: php, mysql, unix-timestamp

i am stuck with trying to figure out this issue its been a long time since i have done mysql calls.

i want to check by rows "user_id" , "entry" and "time"  and see if at least 30 minutes have passed  and if it hasnt alert the user

my code so far is :

```
$chkquery = "SELECT * FROM wpqi_myCRED_log WHERE entry='quiz' AND user_id='1' AND time < unix_timestamp() - 1800";
```

and then if it has been more than 30 minutes then maybe something like this

```
    if( $time_diff >= 1800) {
    echo "Yay! It has been 30 minutes!";

} else {
    $remaining = (1800 - $time_diff );
    echo "Wait! Its not been 30 minutes\n";
    echo "please come back in ".date ( "i:s" , $remaining)." minutes";
}
```

I dont want them to do the quiz more than every 30 minutes
thx in advance

Comment: If you can use a MySQL `DATETIME` field, do it. That means you can do this: `WHERE ... time < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)` and work with the native date/time type. As a bonus these values are human-readable.

Comment: it is part of a wordpress site and i have no control over that i wish they did the plugin that way

Comment: Ah, in that case you're sort of stuck. It's always annoying to have to deal with raw UNIX-type times in MySQL. I think what you need here is a column that represents the next trigger time, you can set that thirty minutes ahead, or if you do trigger it, keep something in the session that represents the last trigger time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok this is what i ended up doing, it is probably messy and can be cleaned up but seems to be working  any suggestions i'm all ears!

```
$user_id ="1";
$refType="completing_quiz_full";

//Minutes allowed between plays
$minutesAllowed = 120;

// take minutes allowed and subract 
$get2hour = time() - ($minutesAllowed * 60);

$chkquery = "SELECT * FROM wpqi_myCRED_log WHERE ref='$refType' AND user_id='$user_id' AND time >= $get2hour order by time desc limit 1";
$chk = mysql_query($chkquery) or die($chkquery."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($chk);

//echo "this many rows meet that criteria is : ". $num_rows. "<br>" ; 

if ($num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($chk, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $entry = $row['entry'];
        $coin = str_replace("%plural%","Burst",$entry);
        echo "<br> You already received ". $coin. "<br>" ;  

       // get time from Table
       $then =$row['time'];
       $played = date('h:i:s A', $then);

      //Get the current timestamp.
       $now = time();

      //Calculate the difference.
      $difference = $now - $then;

      //Convert  to nearest minute
      $minutes = floor($difference / 60);

      //now subtract minutes we allowed
      $timeLeft = $minutesAllowed - $minutes;

      echo "You Have ". $timeLeft. " Minutes till you can play again<br> You Last Played at ". $played. "<BR>";

      }

      } Else {

     echo " now we can show your the content cause its been over 2 hours!! "; 

      }
```